# Add url parameters in python

Tags: python, url

This is my code to access a webpage but I need to add parameters to it:
 1. First parameter is added by reading a line from file
 2. Second parameter is a counter to continuously access pages

```
import urllib2
import json,os

f = open('codes','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    id = line.strip('\n')
    url = 'http://api.opencorporates.com/v0.2/companies/search?q=&jurisdiction_code=%s&per_page=26&current_status=Active&page=%d' 
    i = 0
    directory = id
    os.makedirs(directory)
    while True:
       i += 5
       req = urllib2.Request('%s%s%d' % (url,id, i))
       print req
       try:
          response = urllib2.urlopen('%s%s%d' % (url, id, i))
       except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
          break
       content = response.read()
       fo = str(i) + '.json'    
       OUTFILE = os.path.join(directory, fo)
       with open(OUTFILE, 'w') as f:
           f.write(content)
```

This keeps creating empty directories. I know something is wrong with the url parameters. How to rectify this?

Comment: I think your problem is in your call to `Request`. Off the top of my head, the string format looks wrong. Put the url you're requesting into a variable and print that and see what it looks like.

Comment: This is what it it is printing: http://api.opencorporates.com/v0.2/companies/search?q=&jurisdiction_code=%s&per_page=26&current_status=Active&page=%dae_az5
Appending the parameters at the end.

Comment: I'll add an answer then, I see exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change these bits:

```
    '%s%s%d' % (url,id, i)
```

To this:

```
    url % (id, i)
```

What you're doing now is creating a string like `'<url><id><i>'` instead of substituting in the string.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want to do is to insert `id` and `i` into `url`, but the string formatting you're using here concatenates `url`, `id`, and `i`. Try changing this:

```
req = urllib2.Request('%s%s%d' % (url,id, i))
```

Into this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url % (id, i))
```

Does that give you the result you want?

Also, the string formatting syntax you are using is deprecated; the currently preferred syntax is detailed in [PEP 3101 -- Advanced String Formatting](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/). So even better would be to do:

```
url = 'http://api.opencorporates.com/v0.2/companies/search?q=&jurisdiction_code={0}&per_page=26&current_status=Active&page={1}'
...
req = urllib2.Request(url.format(id, i))
```

Instead of `%s` and `%d` you use curly braces (`{}`) as placeholders for your parameters. Inside the curly braces, you can put a tuple index:

```
>>> 'I like to {0}, {0}, {0}, {1} and {2}'.format('eat', 'apples', 'bananas')
'I like to eat, eat, eat, apples and bananas'
```

If you just use bare curly braces, each placeholder consumes one parameter, and extras are ignored; e.g.:

```
>>> '{} and {} and {}'.format(1, 2, 3)
'1 and 2 and 3'
>>> '{} and {} and {}'.format(1, 2, 3, 4)
'1 and 2 and 3'
>>> '{} and {} and {}'.format(1, 2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    '{} and {} and {}'.format(1, 2)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

You can also use keyword arguments, and therefore dictionary unpacking:

```
>>> d = {'adj':'funky', 'noun':'cheese', 'pronoun':'him'}
>>> 'The {adj} {noun} intrigued {pronoun}.'.format(**d)
'The funky cheese intrigued him.'
```

There are more features, detailed in the PEP, if you're interested.